# how can a password-protected PDF file be opened programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, password-protection

The Adobe IFilter doesn't provide a mechanism to supply a password to open a password-protected PDF file, so it cannot be used to open password-protected files.

I was wondering, is there a relatively straightforward way to programmatically retrieve the actual encrypted data inside the PDF file, decrypt it using a standard cryptography API, and then build a new PDF file with the decrypted data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open a password protected PDF you will need to develop at least a PDF parser, decryptor and generator.  I wouldn't recommend to do that, though. It's nowhere near an easy task to accomplish.

With help of a PDF library everything is much simpler. You might want to try [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) for the task (disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library).

Here is a sample for you task:

```
public static void unprotectPdf(string input, string output)
{
    bool passwordProtected = PdfDocument.IsPasswordProtected(input);
    if (passwordProtected)
    {
        string password = null; // retrieve the password somehow

        using (PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(input, password))
        {
            // clear both passwords in order
            // to produce unprotected document
            doc.OwnerPassword = "";
            doc.UserPassword = "";

            doc.Save(output);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // no decryption is required
        File.Copy(input, output, true);
    }
}
```

Docotic.Pdf can also [extract text (formatted or not) from PDFs](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/pdf-text/extract). It might be useful for indexing (I guess it's what you are up to because you mentioned Adobe IFilter)

Comment: This assumes the password is known by the user.

Comment: @stephanmg The OP did not mention unknown password.

Answer (score 2):

If you use SpirePDF then you can get images of the pages out of an ecrypted PDF like this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using Spire.Pdf;
namespace PDFDecrypt
{
    class Decrypt
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create Document
            String encryptedPdf = @"D:\work\My Documents\Encryption.pdf";
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(encryptedPdf, "123456");

            //Extract Image
            Image image = doc.Pages[0].ImagesInfo[0].Image;

            doc.Close();

            //Save
            image.Save("EmployeeInfo.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            //Launch
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("EmployeeInfo.png");
        }
    }
}
```