# Unable to read secure pdf file using itextsharp

Tags: c#

```cs
string row = string.Empty;
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
string filePath = @"C:\MyPdf\New1Result.pdf";
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath)) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) {
    row = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i); 
    text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
  }
}
```

I am able to read a PDF file using the above code.
I have a PDF file which is secured (SECURED). It is not password protected. I can open it.
When I am trying to read this secured (SECURED) PDF file using above code, it is unable to read it and returns null.

How I can read Secured PDF file?

I tried Spire PDF to remove security of PDF file. After that I am still unable to read content of the file.

Comment: I think you forgot to upload the code above. And what do you mean by reading it? As a stream?

Comment: Yes as a stream.  Code is : string row = string.Empty;
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            string filePath = @"C:\MyPdf\New1Result.pdf";
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath))
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    row = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i);
                    text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
                }
            }

Comment: Don't you mean this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906422/how-can-a-password-protected-pdf-file-be-opened-programmatically

Comment: I got solution...actually my pdf content was in image format...i converted it into text using OCR and then read it.